# Web scraping using axios and jsdom isn't getting image src

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, axios, jsdom

```
const axios = require('axios');

const jsdom = require('jsdom');

const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

(async () => {

 const html = await axios.get('https://mangadex.org/titles/latest');

 const dom = new JSDOM(html.data);

 const title = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll(".chapter-feed__container a div img")[0].src;

if(title) {
 console.log(title);

}
})();
```

I tried above code to get the image url from the website above but it always throws error which I don't know the cause is when I tried scrapping first using console I was successfully here is the code I used in console scrapping

```
var cc=document.querySelectorAll(".chapter-feed__container a div img")[0].src; 
cc;
```

Any suggestions regarding the matter would be of great help. About node.js libraries yes I have them all installed and it's working perfectly.

Comment: view the page source `view-source:https://mangadex.org/titles/latest`, your see `.chapter-feed__container` doesn't exist so jsdom wont see it, if you want to scrape SPA's you need to use puppeteer etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone how's that even possible? It clearly exists did you try entering the code in console? Yes it doesn't exist at first but it exists when i view the page source by selecting the titles and images

Comment: because the site is a nuxt SPA, the DOM is rendered with js, jsdom only sees the source its given it wont spin up the SPA

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so how can I spin up the Spa? Any suggestions plz

Comment: as said use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

Comment: Damn ok thanks i have been practicing jsdom damn would be hard to move on puppeteer anyway thanks

Comment: Any other alternatives to puppeteer?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can't I use HTTP GET request using Axios to the endpoint?